# Is this proof that $2^{23} \equiv 1 \bmod{47}$ correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

By Fermat's little theorem, we have that
$$
2^{46} \equiv 1 \pmod{47}
$$
By writing $2^{23}$ as $\left( 2^{46}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and knowing that

$$
(a^b) \bmod c = ((a \bmod c)^b)\bmod c
$$

we can conclude that

$$
\left( 2^{46}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \bmod{47} =
(2^{46} \bmod{47})^{\frac{1}{2}} \bmod 47 \\
2^{23} \bmod{47}= 1^{\frac{1}{2}} \bmod{47} \\
\therefore 2^{23} \bmod{47} = 1 \bmod{47}
$$

Would this proof be acceptable?

Comment: Why is taking a "square root" okay?

Comment: @Randall that's the exact reason why I'm posting here, I don't know.

Comment: The square root of $1$ mod a prime could be $1$ or $ -1$.   If you tried your approach with $2^{26}$ mod $53$, you would need the other square root of unity

Comment: The proof doesn't work.  Using the same reasoning, you could show that the solution to any congruence of the form $a^b \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ is $a=1.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is invalid. You show that $(2^{23})^2\equiv 1\bmod 47$, but that doesn't imply that $2^{23}\equiv 1\bmod 47$, because $2^{23}$ could equally well be $-1\bmod 47$.

As it happens, $2\equiv 7^2\bmod 47$, so we can write $2^{23}\equiv 7^{46}\equiv 1\bmod 47$. But this doesn't work for non-squares (quadratic non-residues in the jargon) mod $47$; for instance, $5$ is a quadratic non-residue mod $47$, so $5^{23}\equiv -1 \bmod 47$. However, your proof never uses the fact that $2$ is a quadratic residue, so if it were valid, it would show that $5^{23}\equiv 1\bmod 47$, which is false.

Try stepping through your proof after replacing $2$ by $5$, and you should be able to see where it goes astray.

Comment: That is wrong, as the op does not use a square root of $2$, but one of $1$, which always exists. The problem here is that unless we have characteristic $2$ there are always 2 roots of $1$.

Comment: @Lazy: Yes, I realised that I was answering the wrong question. I hope my edit fixes things up.

Comment: After replacing 2 by 5 I can see exactly what I did wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: An aside: There can be more than $2$ solutions to $x^2\equiv 1\pmod m$ $m$ has more than one prime factor. For example. $4^2\equiv 11^2\equiv 1\pmod {15}.$

Answer (score 1):

No, that reasoning is not correct. You are saying: As $2^{46}\equiv 1\bmod 47$ then $2^{23}$ is a square root of $1\bmod 47$. That is true, but there are two possible roots:  $\pm1$. So you have either $2^{23}=1$ or $2^{23}=-1$.

Instead you might evaluate $2^{23}\bmod 47$ by square and multiply:
$$ 2^{23} = 2\cdot 2^{22} = 2\cdot 4^{11} = 8 \cdot 4^{10} = 8\cdot 16^5=128\cdot 256^2 \equiv 34\cdot 21^2 = 34\cdot 441 \equiv 34\cdot 18 =612\equiv 1 \bmod 47$$